# Question testing rails post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jrubyonrails

Using Rails 3.0.3.

I have the following route in routes.rb:

```
 match "user/create_new_password/:reset_password_key" =>"users#create_new_password", :via=>[:get, :post], :as=>:create_new_password
```

When using this route in the view, with a form, it works ok, however I'm not able to test it. I'm doing this in my functional test:

```
test "fail create password with invalid key" do
   post :create_new_password, {:create_new_password=>{:password=>"1", :password_confirmation=>"1"}, :reset_password_key=>"user.reset_password_key"} 
end
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:create_new_password=>{:password=>"1", :password_confirmation=>"1"}, :reset_password_key=>"user.reset_password_key", :controller=>"users", :action=>"create_new_password"}
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was in the parameter value for

```
:reset_password_key
```

```
test "fail create password with invalid key" do
   post :create_new_password, {:create_new_password=>{:password=>"1", :password_confirmation=>"1"}, :reset_password_key=>"user.reset_password_key"} 
end
```

It seems that it's something wrong with the . (dot) in the parameter value.

If I change to other value without the "." (dot), everything is fine. The following works as expected:

```
test "fail create password with invalid key" do
   post :create_new_password, {:create_new_password=>{:password=>"1", :password_confirmation=>"1"}, :reset_password_key=>"user_reset_password_key"} 
end
```