# Rails 3 route problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jrubyonrails

After solving the other [problem with routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948205/question-testing-rails-post) , now I have another one.

I have this route in my routes.rb:

```
match "user/create_new_password/:reset_password_key" =>"users#create_new_password", :via=>[:post, :get], :as=>:create_new_password
```

I can test it in my functional tests like this:

```
test "should create new password " do
    post :create_new_password, {:user=>{:password=>"123456", :password_confirmation=>"123456"}, :reset_password_key=>user.reset_password_key}
end
```

In my view, I have the following form:

```
=simple_form_for @user, :url=>create_new_password_path do |f|
    =f.input :password, :label=>I18n.t("activerecord.attributes.user.email")
    =f.input :password_confirmation, :label=>I18n.t("activerecord.attributes.user.password_confirmation")
    =f.submit I18n.t "activerecord.actions.user.create_new_password"
```

When I submit the form, I get:

```
No route matches "/user/create_new_password/OqQxYTgjYKxXgvbAsTsWtMnIpMOpsjCRzLGZmJZLSbYtjvcvdpO"
```

The big string, is the reset_password_key.

I have tested it in functional tests with the same value for reset_password_key.

The relevant output for rake routes is:

```
create_new_password POST|GET /user/create_new_password/:reset_password_key(.:format) {:controller=>"users", :action=>"create_new_password"}
```

I'm missing something...

Comment: Have to ask: have you started the server since editing the routes? If so, can you post the contents of your `config/routes.rb` file? Thanks and good luck!

Comment: Yes, many times. However I've found the problem. I'm learning it the hard way. I underestimated the cleverness of Rails... Since I'm editing a existing entity, this case a @user, rails is setting the _method to :put.... so, I haven't any put in my route...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered to BinaryMuse's comment, I've found what went wrong... I checked the request in firebug and found that a _method=put was being sent with the POST. Rails cleverness detected that I'm editing and existing instance of User (@user), so it defaults the POTS to a PUT, using the param _method.

The problem is that in my routes I haven't the method PUT in the :via array. Just changed to:

```
 match "user/create_new_password/:reset_password_key" =>"users#create_new_password",:via=>[:get, :put], :as=>:create_new_password
```

And in the controller:

```
def create_new_password
   if request.put?
      #change password
   else
     #render template
   end

end
```